# how to deploy custom iphone apps to devices from a pc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I made an app with xcode, and now I want to share it with a few others.  The problem is I live in different provinces as them and they do not have a mac.  I would rather not go through the app store and I don't mind getting the enterprise developer account if it is necessary.  Does anyone know how I can go about doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is Ad Hoc distribution. You could also use a tool as [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com/), and let your other users download your app over the air.

Comment: Easier to just use a regular .htm page. Free web site hosting for an .htm page is everywhere. Easier than enlisting another company to do something simple. As long as the distribution cert is there it works fine.

Comment: Sure, but have you used TestFlight (or a similar service) @NickTurner? I think that together with their SDK they add a lot of value to the whole process -- nice user management, easy retrieval of UDIDs, checkpoints, remote logging etc

Comment: I agree it adds some value. I currently have clients connect to my site and I just put the redirect into an anchor tag. Only clients I want to down load have access to the link. Achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use testflight or other over the air installation tools. You'll need a valid Ad-Hoc Certificate that includes the devices it's going to be installed on. [Check this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html) for more infos on the topic!
Finally, you can just send them an .ipa if you don't have a server (you can get that from XCode) and they can drag it into iTunes to install the application. It will sync the next time they sync their devices to their computer

Answer (score 1):

1. Just Extract you ipa.
2. In PC/Windows, Drag ipa to iTunes.
3. Synchronize iTunes with device.